# Yarn 2 workspaces, PNP, and unit tests in child workspaces

Tags: node.js, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I have a parent workspace A that has a dependency on a child workspace B. I am using PnP.

If I run `yarn install` in A's directory, the file `.pnp.cjs` is created. That's expected because I need to ensure that when packages A and B depend on a third-party package like `graphql-js`, only a single instance of graphql-js is loaded when A runs, or else [this happens](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/381).

However, maybe I have unit tests or some yarn script I want to run directly inside project B. When I try to run the script, it complains: `Usage Error: The project in B/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed - running an install there might help`. OK, fine, so I run `yarn install` in B's directory, which creates a `.pnp.cjs` file in the directory. Then I try to run the tests/script again in B:

```
Error: Unable to locate pnpapi, the module 'B/[file]' is controlled by multiple pnpapi instances.
This is usually caused by using the global cache (enableGlobalCache: true)

Controlled by:
  B/.pnp.cjs
  A/.pnp.cjs
```

How is it possible to run unit tests or scripts in B, which requires B to have its own .pnp.cjs file, and still have dependencies controlled by A to avoid multiple instances of 3rd-party packages when A runs?